# asp.net mvc: date comparison fails on production server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have a simple comparison in my view to see if an event is in the past:

```
  <% if (model.EventDate < DateTime.Now)
     { %>
  <td style="color: red;">
  <% }
     else
     { %>
    <td>
  <% } %>
```

This works fine on my dev machine, running via Cassini, but on the server it seems to be interpreting 01/12/2010 as Dec. 1, not Jan 12.

How should I be doing this comparison to make sure that it works the same regardless of the runtime environment?

Update:  The EventDate is a DateTime, and is coming from a database, which has the correct date:  select MONTH(EventDate) returns 1, select DAY(EventDate) returns 12.

Comment: So, it is not really this comparison.  When the user enters the EventDate, it is getting parsed like DD/MM/YYYY instead of MM/DD/YYYY, right?

Comment: The EventDate is a DateTime, and it's stored correctly in the database: select MONTH(EventDate) returns 1, select DAY(EventDate) returns 12.

Comment: What are you using as your ORM / DAL ? In other words, how do you parse the value from the database into a datetime?

Answer (score 0):

Comparing two `DateTime` instances in .NET always works. The problem lies when you set `model.EventDate`, maybe you are parsing it from a string.

Answer (score 0):

The server is running under a different culture than your dev box.  This is one of the reasons why people should save dates as [UTC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.touniversaltime(VS.71).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

As a work around you could try adding the following into your web.config (it's a child of <system.web>):

```
<globalization culture="en-US" />
```

HTHs,
Charles